# how to build a connection from c# to sql server using a dialog box?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

Is there a way to show this dialog box inside my c# application in order to generate my connection string to my sql server database?

if so how can I invoke this dialog and retrieve the connection produced?

[image]

if this is not available is there any other ready dialog that can be invoke for similar purpose? (building a valid and tested connection to a sql server database)

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to invoke this window at runtime? To bring it up in general(if using vs) its tools->Connect to Database

Comment: exactly, yes, I believe it must live in a .dll somewhere and I would like to invoke it from inside my application. this dialog come from visual studio 2017, data sources-> new connection

Comment: I don't think you can access this dialog or that you were intended to be able to. If it were possible we would probably have documentation available somewhere. That said, have you considered implementing your own similar dialog and using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class to generate the connectionstring?

Comment: Do you search something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.ui.connectiondlg.connectiondialog?view=sqlserver-2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using .NET Framework 4.8 or below, this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53379.c-working-with-sql-server-connection.aspx#Alternate_method_to_change_connections_at_runtime) points to full Microsoft source code and [code samples](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/MicrosoftConnectionDialog). Taking this code to .NET Core would be possible but time consuming, doubtful it's worthwhile.

Comment: this is wonderful, I am very thankful! I am using  .NET 4.6.1 and it works fine.